# Git pull as another user in shellscript doesnt work on boot but works when I manually execute the shellscript (Raspberry)

Tags: git, raspberry-pi

I am running a kiosk on one user and a Python script on the pi user.
On Reboot a shellscript is executed in

/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

The shellscript does a git pull as pi user and execute the main.py afterwards.
The main.py works but the git pull doesn`t.

```
sudo -H -u pi bash -c 'cd /home/pi/... && git pull git@bitbucket.org:.../....git master'
sudo -H -u pi bash -c '/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/.../main.py' &
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --disk-cache-dir=/dev/null --media-cache-dir=/dev/null --no-sandbox --kiosk --start-fullscreen  --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --disable-pinch --overscroll-history-navigation=0 --disable-features=TranslateUI --app=$url
```

When i execute the shell script manually everything works as intended.

Comment: During boot, many things may not be set up yet. The most likely not-yet-set-up thing is any *security keys* (passwords, etc) that are required to have access to a private repository, but it could be something else, or a combination of two or more things that aren't set up. To debug this, *trace* the operation, logging all the errors somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried a lot more and it seems to be a faoult in my sudoers file<br/> + sudo -H -u pi bash-c git pull git@bitbucket.org:.../....git master<br/>
+ cd /home/pi/mealrevolution
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified<br/>in my sudoers file i have an entry for this `kiosk ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git pull master
`

Comment: Furthermore it works on boot if I use the pi user. I will probably need to give the kiosk user the permission to access the private ssh key in the sudoers file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of stuff i realized there was a problem in my sudoers file. What i needet to do was put in the exact same command as in the script but in this form
`kiosk ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash -c cd /home/pi/... && git pull git@bitbucket.org\:.../....git master`
important is that you need the backslash before the : and that the command is not put in quotation marks, because sudoers file doesnt accept":"and quotation marks. I also changed the command in the script to`sudo  -u pi bash -c 'cd /home/pi/... && git pull git@bitbucket.org:.../....git master'`